# How to Debug Issue With Accidental Compiler/Linker De-Duplication of Non-Duplicate Symbols?

Tags: c++, mysql, clang, homebrew, linkage

Suppose one has encountered a compiler/linker bug with a relatively recent version of Apple's Clang variant that causes said compiler and/or linker to merge the definitions of two completely unrelated symbols from what you suspect are likely two entirely different translation units.  Are there any Clang compiler and/or linker options or usage techniques that would allow one to:

1. Debug exactly how this symbol linkage issue occurred.
2. Mitigate it.

I've looked through `ld`'s `man` page and have come across the `-verbose-deduplicate` linker options, which I suspect (but am not sure) I could add to the linker flags being used by the build scripting for the project that hits this compiler/linker bug in order to debug when it does.  I've also seen the `-no-deduplicate` option for `ld`, but that, frankly, seems like too heavy of a hammer, so to speak.  Are there any compiler visibility attributes or linker-script directives I could invoke for the purpose of solving this?

---

Operating System:  Apple OS X v10.11.6 'El Capitan,' build 15G22010
Toolchain:  Xcode v8.2.1, build 8C1002, with Command-Line Tools v8.2.0.0.1.1480973914
Target Issue:  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86711
Reason:  Solving https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/30405.

Comment: Edited to include Xcode CLT version information.

Comment: @MSalters:  That's just additional machine model information for possible additional help debugging information.  You're right that my hardware shouldn't affect the visibility or occurrence of this issue, though, so I can remove it, or at least consolidate with my device type, if you find it extraneous.

Comment: @MSalters:  As for knowing what the underlying issue is, the linked MySQL issue from upstream tells all:  Clang is merging [`sql/sql_lex.h`'s `SELCT_LEX::is_empty_query()`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-8.0.12/sql/sql_lex.h#L1644-L1649), as called from within the condition on [line 1,509 of `sql/sql_update.cc`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-8.0.12/sql/sql_update.cc#L1509), with [`sql/sql_class.h`'s `TBD::release_resources_done()`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-8.0.12/sql/sql_class.h#L2401) when it really shouldn't be.

Comment: @MSalters:  Edited to remove extraneous hardware details.

Comment: Maybe there's some sort of symbol-aliasing attribute that could come in handy…?  Like '`[[no_alias(`symbol-name`)]]`,' '`[[noalias(`symbol-name`)]]`,' or similar…?  (Or would that control strict aliasing…?)